# iOS v10 or lower: How to add UISearchController in the bottom of navigation bar Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My app's minimum iOS version is 10.3. I am able to add search bar in the bottom of navigation bar for iOS 11. But I want the same for lower version the iOS 11 and it should be programmatic. Please help. Thanks

```
fileprivate func _setupNavigationBar() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Here"
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    } else {
        // TODO: ????????????????
    }
}
```

Comment: You can place it as a `titleView`, or create your own custom navigation bars

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {

var controladorDeBusca: UISearchController!

var resultsTableViewController: ResultsTableViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultsTableViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultsTableViewController") as? ResultsTableViewController

    setUpSearchAtNaviagtion()
}

func setUpSearchAtNaviagtion() {

    controladorDeBusca = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableViewController)
    controladorDeBusca.delegate = self
    controladorDeBusca.searchResultsUpdater = resultsTableViewController
    controladorDeBusca.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true

    controladorDeBusca.loadViewIfNeeded()

    //Configura a barra do Controlador de busca
    controladorDeBusca.searchBar.delegate = resultsTableViewController
    controladorDeBusca.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controladorDeBusca.searchBar.placeholder = "Search place"
    controladorDeBusca.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    controladorDeBusca.searchBar.barTintColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
    controladorDeBusca.searchBar.tintColor = self.view.tintColor

    //Adiciona a barra do Controlador de Busca a barra do navegador
    navigationItem.titleView = controladorDeBusca.searchBar
}
}
```

try this one..

Comment: I don't want to set search bar by replacing title view of navigation bar. I just want to add it below the navigation bar. Also it will be good If I click on seats bar to edit, the navigation bar gets hidden by scroll to top.